# Filter Through HTML Document with OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I am creating an HTML Document through JSON data collected from a SharePoint list. Currently, I have about 80% of my expected result done.

Right now I am not including my fetch to pull the information, because JSON cannot be collected cross-sites due to CORS, so I have included a hard coded version of the JSON collected from the fetch.

As of now, all of my HTML is appending as it should. These are the issues I am currently facing:

- Hide everything(except for the search bar) so it only appears from an onClick or onSearch event.
- Be able to filter through all the JSON objects in the array and only show the Objects with the corresponding date and hide the others (i.e. Raiders & Eagles both have the WeekOf value of 2021-01-31 & the Vikings has the WeekOf value of 2021-03-30. So if I were to search 2021-01-31, only two of the teams will appear).
- Underneath the header "Weekly Team Report", there is a paragraph tag containing the text `<p> Week Of ____</p>`. Where the ____ is, I want the Week Of that is used to search and sort the material to appear (i.e. if I search 2021-01-31, obviously only the Raiders and Eagles reports would show up, but also under the main Weekly Team Report header, the paragraph tag would read `Week of 2021-01-31`.

Here are some documents/articles I have used for research:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

**UPDATE**
I have implemented a Search Bar and Button, which I intend to use for the query/filter as well as hide/show the data which I was searching for. In this case based on the date(WeekOf) data which I entered through the search bar.

- I tried to implement an onClick() & onSearch() function with the button, and the onSearch() failed with `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).search is not a function` and when I implemented the onClick() function, the page loads blank, which is good. But as soon as I click within the search box, the page loads, and when I click search, I get an error 404. I am assuming the search isn't working because I do not have my query/filter set up yet which I need and is essential.

```js
var data = [
    {
      "Team": "Eagles",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Raiders",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Vikings",
      "WeekOf": "2021-03-30",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    }
  ];

function onSuccess(data) {
     var listContent = [];
   
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  + '</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>'
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';
         listContent += '</li>';
 }
   $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
  }
  $(document).click(function(){
    onSuccess(data);
  });
```

```css
h2{
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 20px;
}
h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
span{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#report-summary{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
h4{
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
/* Style the search field */
form.example input[type=datetime] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Style the submit button */
form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #104723;
  color: #b3ab7d;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none; /* Prevent double borders */
  cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Clear floats */
form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form class="example" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
  <input onClick="myFunction()" type="datetime" placeholder="Search for Week Of (MM/DD/YYYY)" id="search">
  <button type="submit" id="myelement"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>

<h1>
Weekly Team Report
</h1>
<p>
Week of 
</p>
<div id="report-summary">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if you understood you correctly. Is that what you want?
Also about the sorting part, there are 2 functions in the end of the code that can sort the content by its date. One is from the oldest to the newest and the other one the opposite.

```js
var data = [
    {
      "Team": "Eagles",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Raiders",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Vikings",
      "WeekOf": "2021-03-30",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    }
  ];

function onSuccess(data) {
     var listContent = [];
   
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<li data-weekOf="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>'
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';

         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
         listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';
         listContent += '</li>';
 }
   $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
   $('li').fadeOut(10);
   $('#under_txt').text(' ');
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    onSuccess(data);
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    $('li').fadeOut(10);
    $('[data-weekOf='+value+']').fadeIn();
  });
  
});
function sortNewestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
function sortOldestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
```

```css
h2{
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 20px;
}
h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

span{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#report-summary{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#search{
  text-align: center;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
h4{
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
#myInput{
  text-align: center;
}
#under_txt{
border-bottom:1px solid black;
margin-left: 5px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<div id="search">
<input id="myInput" type="datetime" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
</div>

<h1>
Weekly Team Report
</h1>
<p>
Week of <span id="under_txt"> </span>
</p>
<div id="report-summary">

</div>
```

Comment: This is somewhat what I was going for, I would still like to have the button beside my search bar as seen in the OP. Also, it is posting a blank bullet point at the top of the HTML which it wasn't doing before.

Besides that, this does somewhat work.